# If $0\notin\partial f(x_k)$ then any $-\xi\in-\partial f(x_k)$ is a descent direction.

Tags: convex-optimization, subgradient

Let $f:R^n\to R$ a convex function, let's supposse $0\notin\partial f(x_k)$. I think any $-\xi\in -\partial f(x_k)$ is a descent direction, i.e., exists $T>0$ such that for all $t\in(0,T]$ $$f(x_k-t\xi)\leq f(x_k).$$
I have tried to prove that, but I don't get it. I have the following results:
If $x^*$ is the minimun of $f$ then $$0>\xi^T(x^*-x_k).$$
Also, for $t>0$ $$f(x_k-t\xi)\geq f(x_k)-t||\xi_k||^2. $$
Now, if what I think is false, please, mention me a counterexample.

Comment: Your notation is a bit peculiar. In any event, it is not true that any $d \in - \partial f(x)$ is a descent, it is true that the negative of the closest point to $\partial f(x)$ is a descent direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \max(100x_1+x_2,-100x_1+x_2)$. Then
$\partial f(0) = \operatorname{co} \{ (100,1), (-100,1) \}$, but
$d=(-100,-1)$ is not a descent direction at $x=0$ since
$0+10000t-t > 0$ for all $t>0$ and so $f(0+td)>0$ for all $t>0$.

Note that the nearest point to $\partial f(0)$ is $(0,1)$ and
$d=-(0,1)$ **is** a descent direction.

Comment: Thank you very much @cooper.hat, I got it, but what do you mean when you say the nearest point to $\partial f(0)$? How do you calculate that?

Comment: @Sofía The point that minimises $\|\xi - 0\|$ for $ \xi \in \partial f(x)$. In this case you can determine the closest point by inspection, in general it requires some computation.